# Is Cambridge UK safe?

Tags: safety, solo-travel, female-travellers, cambridge

Next week I'll be in Cambridge (UK) for a conference. I found a hotel that is quite far away from the center (near Orchard Park). However, I am quite scared of traveling alone, especially by night.

Do you think that Cambridge is safe at night (also outside the city center)?

Any precautions to be taken?

Is it better to go by taxi?

How much does it cost for a half an hour trip?

Comment: Is it for a conference involving the University? If so, try to get Uni accommodation if you can - staying in a college will be much more interesting than a random hotel on the edge of town, plus more convenient!

Comment: Unfortunately they were all taken and thus I had to go in that hotel

Comment: Cambridge is a small city, even living on the outskirts of it is not a big hassle.

Comment: What about taking the bus? Last busway bus through Orchard Park (a hundred meters or so from the two Orchard Park hotels) looks to leave the city at about 11.30pm, so chances are you'll be fine to get back there after dinners for just a few quid!

Comment: Very safe, unless you're an unlocked bicycle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These are the [official statistics](http://www.cambs.police.uk/LocalPolicing/CrimeData.aspx) for Cambridge City, population circa 122,000:

[image: T.SE30723 example]

I admit I nearly choked on my tea on seeing this question’s title but also that a comparison with Cambridge MA is slightly unfavourable – though I suspect that adjustment for differences in classification and reporting would swing that around significantly.

I have not been to Cambridge in a very long time – and a good part of that is because my first impression was that it was exceedingly boring. Packed full of delightful scenery but otherwise DEAD (admittedly in the days when early closing was commonplace - and my visit was on a Wednesday afternoon!)

To query its safety would never have entered my head, so the fact the question has been asked may be a sign that Cambridge UK is much safer than you are used to.

[A1 CABCO TAXIS](http://www.a1cabco.co.uk/) claims to be the largest taxi company in the city of Cambridge. Their web site has a calculator and from the Railway Station to a Travelodge in Orchard Park it estimates as £10.20 (3.6 miles). Google has the travel time as about 15 minutes, so about £20, including a tip, for ½ hr.

Comment: I have to second that. The only thing I'd fear in Cambridge is a drunk driver.

Comment: From my experience of Cambridge it's more likely to be a (terribly polite) drunk student on a bicycle :-) the Mirror show crime stats compared to the UK average, and [Cambridge](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/uk-news/crime-statistics-for-cambridge-3217039) is below average for almost everything, which is remarkable for a city

Comment: @Pnuts Why? It's just the official crime stats against the official populations.

Comment: @pnuts Easy, because a) the local authorities are not equal sizes while the UK average is based on UK population and b) there's a non-symmetrical distribution. There are hundreds of below average crime, very low population authorities, each having little impact on the national average (e.g. Scottish islands, rural areas), and a few high population, high crime areas (e.g. big cities, London boroughs) each with a large impact on national average.

Comment: "which is remarkable for a city" you have to remember that "city" in the UK was traditionally defined by having an anglican cathedral, not by the size of the place (in recent years a handful of places without cathedrals have been given City status but such cities are still the exception not the rule). Cambridge really isn't that big a place.

Answer (score 8):

I visited Cambridge in December 2012 around Christmas in a group of 3 guys. It's not only a beautiful city with a lot of heritage, it feels pretty safe as well.

We stayed at the outskirts of Cambridge at a Holiday Inn,

```
Holiday Inn Express Cambridge
Coldhams Business Park
Norman Way
Cambridge CB1 3LH, United Kingdom
```

It wasn't very difficult to travel around in the city even though I admit it does get a little silent in the night at the outskirts, it was pretty manageable. There were many times we walked through secluded regions without a care in the world. The city centre and the university area is always bustling with joy, so if you can find accomodation near that, it would certainly feel safer and will be more enjoyable.

Taxis run well into the night though in case you feel unsafe. I don't remember the exact rates, but the rates are pretty fair in terms of the standard rates in the UK. I would suspect a 30 minute taxi to run between £12 to £15.

Comment: +1 for the most dangerous thing in Cambridge being the eerie silence, that was my experience too. Some (extremely posh) friends of a family member who lived there used to refer to one street as "the ghetto", and talked as if it was dangerous - I passed through that street the next day, it was just a perfectly normal street but with a couple of charity shops (thrift stores) and a cheap low-end cafe. Cambridge is an unworldy bubble.

Answer (score 8):

Cambridge is very safe when compared with other cities and towns in the UK. But, it may not be very safe compared to your home town or your home country. In the UK built-up areas after dark, the chief danger to a young woman walking alone is drunk young men or roving groups of young men.

If you don't feel safe, by all means arrange for a taxi to and from the hotel.

Another option would be to obtain a bicycle (you can rent a bicycle from the shop just north of the train station exit). By being a bicycle traveler, you will avoid any abuse from pedestrian attackers.  Cambridge is a very safe place for bicycle travel. Outside of Dutch towns, I would rank it as one of the most bicycle friendly towns in the world.

Answer (score 4):

I live in Cambridge and all you’ve got to be worried about is some teenagers messing around or a Chinese tourist running in front of the road with their selfie stick. Although the town is bustling it’s completely safe and you're not going to get robbed unless you're at the strawberry fair. If you have a bike, triple lock it.